# VS Code - "ESLint is not validating any files yet"

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I installed eslint locally and my configuration file contains only this:

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

When I try to run the auto fix of all problems I get the title information.
I tried to reopen VSCode and to force eslint.enable = true in my user settings without success. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened meanwhile but it started to work. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

i also encounter the same problems in my vue project, but  i use another way to have solved it.

your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
  "start": "npm run dev",
  "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src",
  "build": "node build/build.js"
}
```

and then you can execute `npm run eslint`. if --fix is present , you can add it by yourself.

last but not least , you have a nodejs platform and eslint package installed.

Comment: That has nothing to do with VSCode.